# Converting multiple rows with pivot_longer

Tags: r, tidyr

My real dataset is larger, but I tried to shorten it here.
#What I have:

```
Income_100m_total_df <- data.frame(Name = c("Amstelpark", 
                                        "Amstelpark",
                                        "Amstelpark",
                                        "Amstelpark",
                                        "Amstelpark",
                                        "Amstelpark",
                                        "Amstelpark",
                                        "Amstelpark",
                                        "Amstelpark"),
            Income_type_households = c("Mean_low_income_households",
                             "Mean_low_income_households", 
                             "Mean_low_income_households",
                             "Mean_middle_income_households",
                             "Mean_middle_income_households",
                             "Mean_middle_income_households",
                             "Mean_high_income_households",
                             "Mean_high_income_households",
                             "Mean_high_incom_households"),
             Income_households = c(42.333, 42.333, 42.333, 32, 32, 32, 
                                   25.667, 25.667, 25.667),
             Income_type_persons = c("Mean_low_income_persons",
                                     "Mean_middle_income_persons", 
                                     "Mean_high_income_persons",
                                     "Mean_low_income_persons",
                                     "Mean_middle_income_persons",
                                     "Mean_high_income_persons",
                                     "Mean_low_income_persons",
                                     "Mean_middle_income_persons",
                                     "Mean_high_income_persons"),
            Income_households = c(33, 32, 35, 33, 32, 35, 33, 32, 35))
```

What I want

```
Income_100m_total_df_2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Amstelpark", 
                                        "Amstelpark",
                                        "Amstelpark"),
            Income_type_households = c("Mean_low_income_households",
                                       "Mean_middle_income_households",
                                       "Mean_high_incom_households"),
            Income_households = c(42.333, 32, 25.667),
            Income_type_persons = c("Mean_low_income_persons",
                                    "Mean_middle_income_persons", 
                                    "Mean_high_income_persons"),
             Income_households = c(33, 32, 35))
```

I tried to use pivot_longer to achieve this

```
pivot_longer(c(Mean_low_income_household,
             Mean_middle_income_household,
             Mean_high_income_household),
           names_to = "Income_type_households", 
           values_to = "Income_households") %>% 
pivot_longer(c(Mean_low_income_persons, 
             Mean_middle_income_persons, 
             Mean_high_income_persons), 
           names_to = "Income_type_persons", values_to = "Income_persons")
```

However, it only seems to apply to persons and not household, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi,
judging from the example you provided you are not looking to `pivot` your table but simply for a subset of your orginal data. In your example, the desired result is simply rows 1, 5, and 9 from the original data. You can use `slice` to achieve this.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what's the process you want to use to get from the first to the second?

Comment: Hi camille, in the first table there are a lot of iterations so I wanted to get rid of those. By adding two new columns in which the names and values are separated I was hoping to achieve just one table in which there are no iterations (so per park, in this case Amstelpark) I would get just three rows indicating the low middle and high income of both households and persons. I though pivot_longer would get this job done but it seems to apply only the persons and not on the hoouseholds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround of my code that gave me what I wanted:

```
inc_house <- Income_100m_total_df %>% 
group_by(Income_type_households) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(Income_households))

inc_person <- Income_100m_total_df %>% 
group_by(Income_type_persons) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(Income_households.1))

inc_both <- bind_cols(inc_house, inc_person)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the typo in [9,2] ("Mean_high_incom_households"), this should work:

```
cbind( unique(Income_100m_total_df[,1:3]), unique(Income_100m_total_df[,4:5]) )

#        Name        Income_type_households Income_households
#1 Amstelpark    Mean_low_income_households            42.333
#4 Amstelpark Mean_middle_income_households            32.000
#7 Amstelpark   Mean_high_income_households            25.667
#         Income_type_persons Income_households.1
#1    Mean_low_income_persons                  33
#4 Mean_middle_income_persons                  32
#7   Mean_high_income_persons                  35
```

Comment: Thanks Andre! Could you help me with implementing this in my rcode? read_excel("Parks_Buffer_250m_overlap_spatial_join_buurt.xlsx") %>%
  pivot_longer(c(Mean_low_income_household,
                 Mean_middle_income_household,
                 Mean_high_income_household),
               names_to = "Income_type_households", 
               values_to = "Income_households") %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(Mean_low_income_persons, 
                 Mean_middle_income_persons, 
                 Mean_high_income_persons), 
               names_to = "Income_type_persons", values_to = "Income_persons")

Comment: It should work if you save your read output to "Income_100m_total_df" ( Income_100m_total_df <- read.xlsx(...) ), assuming the data still looks like in your example data.frame. You can then do: Income_100m_total_df_2 <- cbind( unique(Income_100m_total_df[,1:3]), unique(Income_100m_total_df[,4:5]) )

Comment: Hi Andre, I tried it and this is wat r gave me: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 60, 59

Comment: Seems like one of your rows differs. Do you still have a typo in your row?  You can test that by running unique(Income_100m_total_df[,1:3]) first, then unique(Income_100m_total_df[,4:5]) and see why there is a row number mismatch.

Comment: I get the same error if I don't correct the typo in your posted example: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3  You ave to change "Mean_high_incom_households" to "Mean_high_income_households"

Comment: Yes It would be fine if the dataset would be the same as in the one I provided in the beginning. However, the real dataset consists of 180 rows and the same 5 columns. I went over it and it seems that column 2 and 4 are fine (both consisting of just 3 variables). Column 3 and 5 are more problematic however as they both give back 57 unique variables, whereas they should be 60 (since 180/3 = 60). Column consists as expected out of 20 unique variables (as I have 20 parks in total instead of just one as I provided in the example).

Comment: It won't be easy to help you with your full data set if you do not explain the logic of how to get to your result.
As of now: your result is simply a subset (no `mutate` or `pivot` or anything else needed).
But I guess for the whole set, the situation is different.

Comment: Hi Cettt, in the first table there are a lot of iterations so I wanted to get rid of those. By adding two new columns in which the names and values are separated I was hoping to achieve just one table in which there are no iterations (so per park, in this case Amstelpark) I would get just three rows indicating the low middle and high income of both households and persons. I though pivot_longer would get this job done but it seems to apply only the persons and not on the hoouseholds